# A proof of existence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I need help proving the following result.

Let $p$ be a positive prime number $\geq 5$, $x$ a non zero integer and $y$ a non zero positive integer such that $x^2-y^p=1$

I've successfully proved that $x$ is odd and $y$ is even. It is then supposed WLOG that $$x=1 \mod [4]$$

I have now to prove the existence of $a$ and $b$ two non zero coprime integers such that $$x-1=2^{p-1}a^p$$ and $$x+1=2b^p$$

The last one is easy to deduce from $$x+1=2 \mod 4$$

However, I don't know why the exponent of $2$ in $y^p$ has to be equal to $p$ (why not a multiple of $p$ ?)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponent of $2$ in $y^p$ need not be exactly $p$. If the exponent is $k\cdot p$, then, since $x \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, we can write

$$x + 1 = 2b^p;\quad x-1 = 2^{k\cdot p-1}c^p$$

with an odd $c$. But then we can absorb a factor $2^{k-1}$ to get

$$x-1 = 2^{p-1}a^p$$

with $a = 2^{k-1}c$.

Comment: That is clear, thanks !